# Assign value to python list without declare the range

Tags: python

Currently, I am using python to handle some excel data.

```
newSet = [[]]
newSet[1][1]="abc"
print(newSet[1][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know have you guys use Lua before.

Lua can assign value to a empty list(list doesn't declare the range).

Can python assign value without declare the range of the list?

Or other way can do this? Because I don't know the range of the list

Comment: Indexes start at 0 in python, and you will need to append a new value to an empty list, e.g.: `newSet[0].append('abc')`. If you are looking for sparse arrays then you might want to look at dictionaries.

Comment: Each time you need to assign value (`a[i]=b`) you can compare `i` and size of `a`. If `a` is too small, you can increase it (use `append`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't know the range of the list in advance, you'd better use `collections.defaultdict` rather than `list` as your container. A simple example is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

newSet = defaultdict(dict)
newSet[1][1] = "abc"
print(newSet[1][1])
```

The result is as you expected:

```
abc
```

Comment: The correct solution is to use `append()`, not to emulate another language's arbitrary indexing with a `defaultdict`.

Comment: If the index does matter, `defaultdict` will be the right way.